# c++ _T gives "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I get the error "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" on the _T... It goes away if i remove the " + i + " part. my current understanding ist that _T casts it as a string, and it does not accept a variable that is only present in the current scope.. Is that correct? How would this be done properly?

```
for (int i = 0; 15; i++)
{
    if (_tcsicmp(dataIdent, _T("ColorH_Low[" + i + "]")) == 0) {        // (2)
        ptrSetupData->ColorH_Low[i] = data->GetIVal();      // (2)
    }


}
```

Comment: `_T` (and all of the `T`-stuff) is a hacky macro from 1995 when Windows did not handle Unicode at all. Just use `std::wstring`.

Comment: thanks, but replacing _T with std::wstring gives the message ''no suitable conversion function from "std::wstring" to "const wchar_t *" exists'... is _tcsicmp also one of those t-stuff thingies?

Comment: Yes it is. `std::wstring` has an operator `==` which does comparison ;)

Comment: not sure I understand... (sorry, first time for me with C++ and trying to understand what is going on)

Comment: Your line in particular would be written `if(dataIdent == L"ColorH_Low[" + std::to_wstring(i) + L"]")`. I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not the place for an in-depth C++ course though.